# Probability of choosing a defective appliance

Tags: probability

Amongst $15$ appliances there are $10$ functional and $5$ defective. We choose $3$ appliances at random. What is the probability of

A) all of them being functional

B) exactly one being defective

The total number of possible choices is $15\cdot 14\cdot 13$, number of choices containing only functional appliances is $10\cdot 9\cdot 8$ so 
$$P(A)=\frac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8}{15\cdot 14\cdot 13}$$

As for B), I tried a similar approach. We have $5$ possibilities of choosing a defective appliance and choose the other two from the functional ones so

$$P(B)=\frac{5\cdot 10\cdot 9}{15\cdot 14\cdot 13}$$
This is wrong however. I know that I am missing something but I am not sure why exactly this approach does not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in $B$ is that in the way you calculate the probability you somehow *force* the first appliance to be defective. This is not necessary so. You can have exactly $1$ defective appliance, and that can be the second or the third. So, you have in total $3$ ways for this to occur. Multiplying the fraction on the RHS with $3$ should therefore yield the correct result, i.e. $$P(B)=3\cdot\frac{5\cdot10\cdot 9}{15\cdot14\cdot13}$$

---

This was not necessary in A) - and therefore you were mislead - since in A) there is only one way to choose $3$ functional appliances.

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to choose $1$ out of $5$ defective appliances is $\binom{5}{1}=5$

The number of ways to choose $2$ out of $10$ functional appliances is $\binom{10}{2}=45$

The number of ways to choose $3$ out of $15$ any type of appliances is $\binom{15}{3}=455$

Hence the probability of choosing $1$ defective and $2$ functional is $\frac{5\cdot45}{455}=\frac{45}{91}\approx0.5$